# Isosceles triangle has two sides of length $2\pi$ and area $\pi$. Find the third side and the three angles.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

An isosceles triangle with two sides $\tau = 2\pi$ (one is the base), altitude 1, and area $\pi$. What is the length of third side and the three angles (in both radians and degrees)?

Note: not a right triangle, so values are not the same as Archimedes's triangle for the area of a disk.

Comment: What have you tried?  You have the area.  Imagine bisecting the angle between the two $2\pi$ sides to get two right triangles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say your triangle is $ABC$ with $AB=AC=\tau$ and the altitude $BH=1$, where $H$ in $AC$. You can use pythagorean theorem to get $AH=\sqrt{AB^2-BH^2}=\sqrt{\tau^2-1^2}$. Then, $HC=AC-AH=\tau-\sqrt{\tau^2-1^2}$. Finally, use pythagorean theorem again to compute that 
$$BC=\sqrt{BH^2+HC^2}=\sqrt{1+(\tau-\sqrt{\tau^2-1^2})^2}$$.

To obtain the angles, you express the angles in terms of inverse trig functions, for instance $\angle A=\arcsin(BH/AB)=\arcsin(1/\tau)$, and so on.

Comment: The last two angles can be done using: $\angle B = \angle C$ and $ (\pi - \arcsin(1/\tau))/2$. Thanks. Only one real use of $\pi$ nice and clean with $\tau$.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

- Find $AD$ by Pythagoras
- Find $DC$ by subtraction
- Find $BC$ by Pythagoras
- Find angles by trigonometry

[image]

Comment: how did you draw that

Comment: is this geogebra

Comment: @endgameendgame: MSPaint - it is not to scale